# Autocompletion from .netrc in Emacs

Tags: emacs, ftp, .netrc

I use Emacs at work and at home, both on Windows XP, both EmacsW32. On my work computer, if I setup FTP login details for a site, for example:

```
machine ftp.stackoverflow.com login codinghorror password orange
```

then if I want to ftp there from Emacs, I just type

```
/ftp.s<tab>
```

and it knows from my .netrc that it can autocomplete to

```
/ftp.stackoverflow.com:
```

which is exactly what I want. On my home computer, the autocomplete just doesn't work, although it does once I'm on the server, so if I type:

```
/ftp.stackoverflow.com:public_h<tab>
```

it will autocomplete the `html`. Does anyone have any ideas as to why this might be?

Comment: what do you mean by "once I'm on the server"?

Comment: Once I'm on the server means once Emacs has connected to the FTP server.

Comment: So, if I type in `/ftp.stackoverflow.com:public_h<tab>`, Emacs will connect to the remote server and work out the autocompletion.

Comment: I'd like to know this too. But I suspect the reason is that TRAMP is not yet loaded when you're just writing "/ftp.s" (that could after all be a valid local folder), so Emacs doesn't know it could autocomplete.